# SSRS dashboard layout : set up height of all graphs the same

Tags: sql, reporting-services

[image]I am trying to build SSRS dashboard. In first tablix I have two tables. And rest 3 have graphs. I would like to set up height of all to same. I am having trouble with fist two tables. And getting extra spaces between all.

For first two tables I used rectangle and also rest three. But still getting extra space after first two tables and before graph number 3.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because SSRS doesnt know the height of the tables. This depends on the rows. You can either put the tables on the bottom and on top the charts or you add a page break after the first 3 visuals.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually max height is fixed. I mean there would be max 13 rows all times. Or if they apply filter. then might be one or two rows. But max would ne 13. So is there way to fix max height and then I can fix height of chart number two to same as table number one. And then below there I can put chart number three. Because of end user I can't put table at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've created multiple dashboards over the years using SSRS and I've found the best way to do this is to literally restrict the table data to a set number of records so you can gauge the height of the full tablix and adjust the charts accordingly. I did try using dynamic lengths based on records returned but it wasn't viable.

A good idea is to also place objects within rectangles when creating dashboards, its handy if you have more than one row of visuals and you want the next row to all be lined up.